# BigQuery grant access to specific datasets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have a user which is not currently a member of my GCP project, for which I am an owner. I would like to grant them read write and delete privileges for specific datasets. I know that I can add them to the project with the "BigQuery User" role but this gives them permissions for all datasets. How do I add them to the project but only give them permissions for specific datasets?

Comment: Did you try to go to BigQuery UI, select your dataset, click on `Share Dataset` and grant the role security admin on the user that you want?

Comment: No, I'll try that

Comment: It didn't work just sharing the dataset, it only works if I give them permissions at the project level, but then they have access to all datasets.

Comment: What did not work? Do you have an error, or it did not work as expected?

Comment: It simply doesn't let the user into the project if I only given them access to the dataset. I need to give them something like project viewer role to let them into the project, but then they can see all the datasets.

Comment: Project viewer, it can see all the resources. Which resource do you want to allow and which one do you want to disallow?

Comment: I have now tried just giving them compute viewer project role, with only certain bq datasets shared and this almost works - they can access the project, and only the shared datasets are visible, however the user can't run queries on them, even though I shared the dataset with Owner role. Any ideas?

Comment: For running queries on BigQueries, the user needs the role `roles/bigquery.jobUser`

Answer (score 7):

There are two scenarios to consider when [sharing datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset).

1. Only sharing the datasets (no access to the project):

You can [share](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset) the dataset from the BigQuery web UI, using a predefined IAM [role](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) with the access you want to provide. Keep in mind that with this approach, the user will only have access to the dataset, and to do something like query a table they'll require a GCP project of their own, where they have the "bigquery.jobs.create" [permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs) at a project level, which is required for this.

A clear example on how this works is a public dataset, where you have access to the data, but you have to query it from your own project.

2. Sharing datasets and project access (to run queries):

This option requires as the first one, [share](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset) the dataset, and additionally, requires some permissions at a level project for specific operation, like run queries. To allow a user to run queries on your project (the billing of this executions will go to your billing account), you need to provide the user with the "bigquery.jobs.create" [permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs) at a project level; this permission won't provide access to the datasets, it allows to do queries within the project.

If by some reason you only provide the "bigquery.jobs.create" permission and no dataset access, they will only be able to query [public datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data).

For this particular case you could provide the "BigQuery Job User" predefined IAM [role](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.jobUser) at the project level, which from the 3 roles that include the required permission is the one with the lower scope.

Comment: It is worth noting that giving Job user permission on a project give it for data stored in ALL projects accessible to the user. The user can then make a multi-Tb request on a public dataset or any other project it has access to and YOUR project will be charged for it. This is a big downside of the BigQuery IAM implementation at the moment.

Comment: Not sure if I would consider that a downside. It is important to know that of course, and as I mention on my answer **the billing of these executions will go to your billing account**. However, the Job user permission grants execution/process/query capability, you could use that within the data access you have. Thus, data access and processing permissions are separated, allowing to grant access to data, without providing the query permissions. I think this is for the better, this way you don't need to grant the Job user permission and get billed for people querying your data.

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that if you are a BigQuery admin or project owner, part of your responsibility is to make sure you grant the Job user permissions only to users that need it, make good use of it and are aware of the pricing. Nonetheless, if you want to be on the safe side, you can make use of the usage quotas, or [controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on-demand_query_cost_controls) to make sure there are not unexpected large-expensive query executions, when providing this kind of access.

Comment: I disagree. For large company admins this behaviour is a potential nightmare. It means any employee with job user permission on at least 1 project can do personal or "shadow IT" BigQuery side projects under the radar, making any company wide governance hard to implement. Quotas do not change that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to share only single dataset with them. The following worked for me:

1. Choose the dataset you want to share, click share dataset: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwYe8.png)
2. Enter email, click BigQuery -> BigQuery Admin
3. Save

It should work on dataset level, and would not give access to all datasets, see details in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control:

> You can also assign roles at the dataset level to provide access only to one or more datasets. In the Cloud IAM policy hierarchy, BigQuery datasets are child resources of projects. Tables and views are child resources of datasets — they inherit permissions from their parent dataset.

Also, there are other ways to share datasets here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#console

Thanks,
Alexey

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesn't let the user into the project if I only share the dataset. I need to give them something like project viewer role to let them into the project, but then they can see all the datasets.

Comment: They shouldn't need project viewer role to access single dataset. Just dataset-level sharing is enough.

Comment: What is the error you see when user has access to dataset but not the project? I just tried again and I can access dataset without a problem, even though I don't have project-level role.